# Соединение двух Bitmap с установкой прозрачности

Tags: java, android, изображения, bitmap

У меня есть 2 картинки `Bitmap`. Мне нужно сохранить в галерею картинку, полученную склеиванием этих двух, установив прозрачность для первой.

Код для сохранения:

```
String filename = "pippo.png";
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dest = new File(sd, filename);
Bitmap bitmap = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Пример результата:

[image: пример]

Comment: Ну а где собственно вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос же описал, Как мне склеить 2 картинки в одну?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11740676/3212712), модифицировав код для своих нужд.

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Resources res = getResources();


    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.test1); //blue

    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.test2); //green
    Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap1);
    Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2);


    drawable1.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    drawable2.setBounds(150, 150, 350, 350);
    drawable1.draw(c);
    drawable2.draw(c);


} catch (Exception e) {
}
return bitmap;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а не знаете как установить прозрачность элемента 'Bitmap' ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот код для задачи прозрачности:

```
Bitmap bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.main_logo_2);       
Paint transparentpainthack = new Paint();
transparentpainthack.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, transparentpainthack);
```

Себе уже задачу решил , думаю пользователям будет полезно)